# Android Bluetooth Low Energy WriteCharacteristic(byte) is false

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to transfer a file by BLE communication.

I sent each data to five Characteristics, but I receive "false" of writeCharateristic().

I expected this to be a MTU problem.

But when I did the same transfer in the top level function I got "true"

I'm suspecting BluetoothGatt function. can you give me some advice?

Comment: Can you give us some more details? Please [edit] your question and add some source code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.